# onSnapshot triggers to often

Tags: javascript, reactjs, firebase, google-cloud-firestore

I implemented the firestore onSnapshot emthode into my React project and it seems to work. Sadly it works a little bit to good, the onSnapshot method triggers way to often.

```
const Remote = () => {
const [umbrellas, setUmbrellas] = useState([]);
const [loaded, setLoaded] = useState(false);
const [currentUmbrella, setCurrentUmbrella] = useState(null)
let umbrellaName = ""
let umbrellaposition = ""

const firebaseConfig = {
    ...
};

const app = initializeApp(firebaseConfig);
const db = getFirestore(app);

useEffect(() => {
    wait();
    console.log('Hallo');
}, []);

function wait() {
    setTimeout(function () {
        setLoaded(true);
    }, 3000);
}

useEffect(() => {
    const getUserInterval = setInterval(() => {
        const user = getAuth().currentUser;
        console.log(user);
        if (user !== null) {
            clearInterval(getUserInterval);
            getAllUmbrellas(user.email);
        }
    }, 300);

    return () => clearInterval(getUserInterval);
}, []); // Make sure to clean up the interval on component unmount

async function getAllUmbrellas(searchString) {
    const umbrella = [];
    const q = query(collection(db, 'Fernsteuerung'));
    const querySnapshot = await getDocs(q);
    querySnapshot.forEach((doc) => {
        umbrella.push(doc.data());
    });
    console.log('got all');
    filterObjectsByAuthorizedUser(umbrella, searchString);
}

const q = query(collection(db, "Fernsteuerung"), where("MAC", "!=", "null"));
const unsubscribe = onSnapshot(q, (querySnapshot) => {
    querySnapshot.docChanges().forEach((change) => {
        console.log("Change type:", change.type);
        console.log("Changed document data:", change.doc.data());
    });
});


useEffect(() => {
    // Effect to handle state update after filtering
    console.log('Umbrellas updated:', umbrellas);
}, [umbrellas]); // Add umbrellas as a dependency to this useEffect

const filterObjectsByAuthorizedUser = (objectList, searchString) => {
    const filteredList = objectList.filter(
        (obj) => obj.AuthorizedUser && obj.AuthorizedUser.includes(searchString)
    );
    setUmbrellas(filteredList);
};

async function submitRemoteControlle() {
    const docRef = doc(db, "Fernsteuerung", "Fenrsteuerung:"+currentUmbrella.MAC);
    await updateDoc(docRef, {
        ausstehend:true,
        name:umbrellaName,
        Schirmposition:umbrellaposition
    });
}

async function fetchData(Mac) {
    const docRef = doc(db, "Schirme", Mac);
    const docSnap = await getDoc(docRef);

    if (docSnap.exists()) {
        setCurrentUmbrella(docSnap.data());
        console.log(docSnap.data())
    } else {
        // docSnap.data() will be undefined in this case
        console.log("No such document!");
    }
}

return (
    <>
        {!loaded ? (
            <div className="lds-facebook">
                <div></div>
                <div></div>
                <div></div>
            </div>
        ) : (
            <div className={'Background'}>
                <div className={'LeftBar'}>
                    <img src={require('../svg/SSonsiName.png')} alt="logo" />
                    <div className={"Line"}></div>
                    <button onClick={() => console.log(umbrellas)}>Test</button>
                    {umbrellas &&
                    umbrellas.map((data) => {
                        return (
                        <div key={data.id} className={"Entries"} onClick={()=>{fetchData(data.MAC)}}>
                            <div>
                                <div></div>
                                <h1>{data.name}</h1>
                            </div>
                        </div>
                    )
                    })}
                    <div className={"Avatar"}>
                        <div className={"AvatarLeft"}>
                            <div></div>
                            <h1>Benjamin Galler</h1>
                        </div>
                        <div className={"ExitSVG"}></div>
                    </div>
                </div>
                <div className={"Right"}>
                    {currentUmbrella !== null ?
                        (<div>
                            <input id={"name"} placeholder={currentUmbrella.Name} onChange={(e)=>{umbrellaName = e.target.value}}/>
                            <br/>
                            <input id={"position"} placeholder={currentUmbrella.Schirmposition} onChange={(e)=>{umbrellaposition = e.target.value}}/>
                            <br/>
                            <button onClick={()=>{submitRemoteControlle()}}>Submit</button>
                        </div>)
                        :
                        (<h1>No Umbrella selected</h1>)}
                </div>
            </div>
        )}
    </>
);
};

export default Remote;
```

Here's the full code of my React component. Anyways, this most likely is the important part:

```
const q = query(collection(db, "Fernsteuerung"), where("MAC", "!=", 
"null"));
const unsubscribe = onSnapshot(q, (querySnapshot) => {
    querySnapshot.docChanges().forEach((change) => {
        console.log("Change type:", change.type);
        console.log("Changed document data:", change.doc.data());
    });
});
```

Anyways, I think this still might be usefull for you.
Furthermore, here is the output I get:
[Output](https://i.stack.imgur.com/40iyK.png)
As mentioned, this output is generated multiple times when the onSnapshot function is triggered.

To recreate the issue:

1. Create a React component, install the necessary npm packages, and initialize the admin config (as illustrated in the code).
2. Implement the onSnapshot function, ensuring to adjust the collection path to your test collection (as shown in the code).
3. Modify document values and observe the web console.

(Note: A personal Firebase project is required for this process.)

Comment: Your code is issuing the query at every single re-render of your component, and nothing is unsubscribing all those queries.  So your callback is going to be invoked a *lot* more often than you expect.  You need to use a react hook to manage this, just like any other API call that needs to happen only once.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

More info would be helpful, but it smells like a react component is not properly destroying a listener at the end of it's life..which can cause snowballs like this.

If you're using useEffect(), make sure you add a return function in the same place you set up your listener

```
useEffect( ()=>{
    //subscribe some events

    return () => {
      //unsubscribe those events here
    }
})
```

If you're using older React, set a `componentWillUnmount()`

Comment: Firstly, thanks for both of your fast feedback.

I updated the question; I hope it helps you. The useEffect approach sounds interesting, but what should I use to trigger this useEffect? with `[]`?

Comment: Thanks, guys!

I found my mistake, now I use a useEffect and unsubscribe from the listener. Both of you were a great help!